# DocumentDB vs Key-Value DB with hierarchy Performance

Tags: performance, mongodb, redis, couchdb, key-value

First things first: I know Key-Value DB are by far best the performing databases. My assumption is that this is due to their simplicity (sticking to very few primitives).
(**EDIT2**: Obviously also due to beeing mostly held in Memory)

Anyway what about more complex datastructures like hierarchy trees and the likes. With DB like redis you have to build a structure based on "flat" hashes with links whereas with document DBs like couchdb you just build up the structure yourself like:

```
"menu": {
    "id": "file",
     "value": "File",
     "popup": {
        "menuitem": [
             {
              "value": "New",
              "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
              },
              {
              "value": "Open",
              "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
              },
              {
              "value": "Close",
              "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
              }
       ]
}
```

If I have structures like this, does it even make sense to use redis performance and usabilitywise?

Interestingly key-value and document Databases get compared 1:1 very often, while serving a different purpose or/and use-case IMHO.

**EDIT:**

What I'm looking for: generally I would like to have a JSON-like DB store, which is giving me the ease of defining and building complex structures on the fly and getting the good things from use of a Databases-System (failover, speed, ...).

Thank you!

Comment: "First things first: I know Key-Value DB are by far best performing databases." Maybe some are, but i wouldn't consider it to be a universal truth. I don't understand what you're looking for. You'll need to see how your requirements and knowledge, and IT folks match with the various platforms. What are your requirements for rich queries, etc.?

Comment: You're right there's _never_ a universal truth. But making bold assumption often helps and improves discussions. No offense :-)
For now I dont need rich queries, I know DocumentDBs like Mongo and Couch are way better at this. So I was mainly wondering about performance aspect. When using them similarly (same/similar datastructures).

Comment: StackOverflow works better when questions aren't discussions though. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @WiredPrairie you're right. I didnt mean discussion as such. More like getting new views, good input and pointers from different persons.

Comment: (In other words, a discussion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have structures like this, does it even make sense to use redis
>   performance and usabilitywise?

Structure you depicted consists of embedded data in a json document, however even with document databases there is still a difference between [embedded](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#embedding) and [referenced/linked](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#referencing) data. If you embedd a lot of data into single document, you can end up with performance issues and data fragmentation. Referencing is on the other hand more flexible, but requires some joining logic. To sum it up - it depends on your domain model and problem your are trying to solve. Regarding redis there are libraries like [ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/) which provide more OOP based higher level data abstraction.

> What I'm looking for: generally I would like to have a JSON-like DB
>   store, which is giving me the ease of defining and building complex
>   structures on the fly and getting the good things from use of a
>   Databases-System (failover, speed, ...).

Although mongodb is probably the most popular document database followed by couchdb, you can also try to look at other solutions like arangodb or orientdb. Each of them is built on top of some philosophy which might provide benefits in specific areas compared to other solutions, e.g. couchdb's map-reduce way of querying might not be suitable for everyone, but it's durable.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I think I'm going for the Redis Set + JSON approach. It seems the best combo of the bunch for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Key-Values stores like Redis perform so well because they store data in-memory, which you can read/write many times faster than data stored on disk.

The trouble with in-memory storage is fault tolerance: if Redis turns off unexpectedly, memory clears, and all your data is lost. So, Redis is appropriate when you're reading and writing data frequently, but you don't mind if this data is lost. For example: login sessions, where losing data means users just sign in again.

CouchDB and other document stores swap speed for fault tolerance, ensuring your data is safer under more circumstances. Document stores like CouchDB also provide queries, letting you search and parse your data, which you can't do with Redis. A document store like CouchDB is appropriate when you're reading and writing data that you can't afford to lose arbitrarily.

Comment: AFAIK Redis is also capable for fault tolerance, I just depends on how often you sync to the Filesystem. But you're right, this is another major difference in the way of how they are implemented. So let's assume we backup our memory db aggressively to disk, how would they compare with my example. I imagine that joining several hashes together in Redis for implementing some sort of hierarchy would slow things down as well. I generally wonder if storing nested datastructures in redis is just plain wrong and sort of not the right tool for the task.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the more complicated your data is, the more inappropriate Redis is as a solution.